# Adding a list to a list, Then adding another list to the list you just added

Tags: python, list

Basically, i'm trying to encode a int by using lambda functions and assiging them to a list.

Current implementation:

```
succ = (lambda f: lambda n: f(n))

def encode(i):
    zeroList = []
    secondaryList = []
    encodedList = [succ]

    if i == 0:
        return zeroList  
    else:
        x = i - 1
        for x in range(0, x):
            secondaryList.append(succ)
        encodedList.append(secondaryList)
    return encodedList
```

so the output of encode(4) is currently:

```
[<function <lambda> at 0x0000024D71943DC8>, [<function <lambda> at 0x0000024D71943DC8>, <function <lambda> at 0x0000024D71943DC8>, <function <lambda> at 0x0000024D71943DC8>]]
```

when I want it to be:

```
[fun, [fun, [fun, [fun, fun]]]]
```

so i keep adding a list to the list i'm currently on, if that makes sense.

Comment: Are you trying to implement Church numerals (in which case, your definition of `succ` is wrong)?

Comment: well kinda, what i'm asked to do is f(n),[f(n),f(n)] and so on but it's similar to church.

what would churchsucc be?

Comment: Is there even a reason for `succ` (or any other function) to be stored in the lists? The entire encoding seems based on the *number* of things stored in the list; even the nesting doesn't seem relevant. (Why `[fun, [fun, [fun, fun]]` instead of `[fun, fun, fun, fun]`? Why `[fun, fun]` instead of `[fun, [fun]]`?)

Comment: there isn't really a reason as far as I can tell, just an exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for `[fun, [fun, [fun, [fun, fun]]]]` output type :

```
succ = (lambda f: lambda n: f(n))
def encode(i):
    return [succ] + [encode(i-1)] if i>0 else succ
print(encode(4))
```

**Output** :

```
[<function <lambda> at 0x7fb72267d710>, [<function <lambda> at 0x7fb72267d710>, [<function <lambda> at 0x7fb72267d710>, [<function <lambda> at 0x7fb72267d710>, <function <lambda> at 0x7fb72267d710>]]]]
```

Try this for `[fun, [fun, [fun, [fun]]]]` output type :

```
def encode(i):
    return [succ] + [encode(i-1)] if i>1 else [succ]
print(encode(4))
```

**Ouput** :

```
[<function <lambda> at 0x7fb72267d710>, [<function <lambda> at 0x7fb72267d710>, [<function <lambda> at 0x7fb72267d710>, [<function <lambda> at 0x7fb72267d710>]]]]
```

Comment: wait there seems to be one issue, the end of the list retruns (fun, fun]]) rather than (fun, [fun]]) is there any way to fix that?

Comment: @Lamebro1 In your question, you mentioned that you wanted the output to be like `[fun, [fun, [fun, [fun, fun]]]]`

Comment: oh my bad! I meant to write fun, [fun]] - sorry for the typo

Comment: @Lamebro1 Check whether the updated answer solves your problem.